# How to allocate multi dimensional outputbuffer to feed Android Tflite's interpreter.run()?

Tags: java, android, arrays, tensorflow

I try to run a version `posenet` (which is a CNN) on an android app with tflite.

The app is based on the GPU delegate demo:

(1) https://medium.com/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-now-faster-with-mobile-gpus-developer-preview-e15797e6dee7

(2) https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/java/demo

Posenet takes an Image as Input and computes as output multiple arrays of the shape:
`1x14x14x17, 1x14x14x34, 1x14x14x32, 1x14x14x32`

I know how to allocate a bytebuffer for the image, so thats not the problem.

But how do i allocate a buffer for that output to be able to successfully feed the input and output buffer to the interpreter like:

```
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
Interpreter tflite;

ByteBuffer input = null;
input = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(...);
output = ?

tflite.run(input,output);
```

I tried something like this for the float version:

```
float[][][][] output = null;
output = new float[1*14*14*17][1*14*14*34][1*14*14*32][1*14*14*32];
```

but this leads to a memory oom. So how do I correctly allocate a buffe for the output with an array with the right dimensions. (I am not so used to java, more to python)

**EDIT:**

I want four nested 4-dimensional arrays. Because thats whats coming out of the model. something like this:

```
float[][][][] out1 = new float[1][14][14][17];
float[][][][] out2 = new float[1][14][14][34];
float[][][][] out3 = new float[1][14][14][32];
float[][][][] out4 = new float[1][14][14][32];
float[] output = new float[out1, out2, out3, out4];
```

But this does not work

Answer (score 2):

@Chris623's answer still would not work for use in tflite. Using interpreter.run() would not work in the case where you need to allocate memory for a multi-dimensional output array.

You would rather need to use interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(). Sample code is shown below for your 4 arrays.

```
float[][][][] out1 = new float[1][14][14][17];
float[][][][] out2 = new float[1][14][14][34];
float[][][][] out3 = new float[1][14][14][32];
float[][][][] out4 = new float[1][14][14][32];

Map<Integer, Object> outputs = new HashMap<>();
outputs.put(0, out1)
outputs.put(1, out2)
outputs.put(2, out3)
outputs.put(3, out4)

interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputs, outputs)
```

This should help you map your output arrays for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

To create a multidimensional array of the form 1x14x14x17 you can use:

```
float[][][][] output = new float[1][14][14][17];
```

It's equivalent for other dimensions like 1x14x14x32:

```
float[][][][] output = new float[1][14][14][32];
```

If you receive multiple multidimensional arrays of the form [a][b][c][d][e] then maybe you would need to pass in only:

```
float[][][][][] output;
```

Hopefully the function you are calling will set the dimensions as required. You could then retrieve them using the `.length` parameter.

Comment: how would i combine two of those multidimensional arrays into one?
`float[][][][] out1= new float[1][14][14][17];`
`float[][][][] out2= new float[1][14][14][32];`
`float[][] output = new float[out1][out2];`

Would this work?

Comment: This method would not work when using with the tflite interpreter.run() method. you would need to create a hashmap of the output array objects. I have represented the same in the answer below.